# Ubuntu freezes when I copy/move file into home folder

Tags: 12.04, screen, libreoffice, freeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Since yesterday when I open the home folder and I try to copy, move, cut a file from there, the screen freezes, I'm not able to click in any icon or menu, but <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> still work, and when I return to the GUI (by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd>), the screen turns black and only showing the mouse cursor. This happens only in my session and strangely, is the only folder where happening this, even when I copy or move a file from other folder to home, without opening the home (by bookmark or address bar).

I tried to move all the files (not the folders) in home to other folder from another session, and it worked, but back on my session I still have the same problems. I had no problems when I open these files (mostly of them images), before and after I have moved them, except with the .odt files, LibreOffice also freezes the screen when I try to open it (or a .odt file). I have LO from ppa, so I purge it, but nothing changed, and obviously, when I open these files and LO from another session, works perfectly...

To sum up, the home's files and the LibreOffice suite freezes the screen. Halp!

I have 12.04, and I use Gnome fallback.

## FIXED

...Or I thing so. the problem has been in the File Watcher compiz's plugin, I turn off this and EVERYTHING's fine now. All's ok except I still do not know what doing this plugin... beside freeze the screen :P

I leave [here](http://ubuntuone.com/0P73bqWtoXRdIoUbw6OPaL) the X.org's log's file, a bit late, and I don't know if it's related to the problem or not, but is the only one I find apparently related in the /var/log.

Comment: Is your home folder mounted on a separate hard disk? If so, perhaps that disk is failing physically and needs to be replaced.

Comment: Could be quite a variety of things.  Sometimes errors appear in your log files.  Have you scanned through your logs for relevant error messages?

Comment: Encrypted home or quotas present?  Encrypted home freezes sometimes on superlarge copies.

Comment: @Bryce nope, I will seek as check them asap

Comment: @AbrahamVanHelpsing None of two

Comment: Yep, in a separate partition, in the same hard disk that / but in the disk utility this hd appears healthy.

Comment: I think it makes sense to reopen this, so the OP can post the solution as an answer.